# What is the unit vector in electric field formula?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, coordinate-systems, coulombs-law

What is the $\hat{r}$ (vector) in the formula $\vec{E} = k\frac{q}{r^2} \hat{r}$ for the electric field ? Why we dont use the vectors $\vec{i},\ \vec{j},\  \vec{k}$? Also why this vector doesn't appear in the formula where field is the gradient of potential where we have $\vec{i},\ \vec{j},\  \vec{k}$ (unit vectors)?

Comment: Which formula are you referring to and where did you find it?

Comment: http://www.softschools.com/formulas/images/electric_field_formula_5.png

Comment: I still don't see a formula in your question.

Comment: I think he’s talking about $\nabla=\hat{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}...$.

Comment: @adosar, you can write the gradient operator in spherical coordinates and then it involves the spherical unit vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the field of a point charge $q$ (at the origin) in Cartesian coordinates as

$$\mathbf{E}=q\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

or you can use spherical coordinates to write it as

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}.$$

The latter is simpler and easier to remember, and it makes the spherical symmetry obvious.

(By the way, I’ve written these formulas in Gaussian units, where the Coulomb constant is 1. Stick a $k$ or a $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ in front if you prefer other unit systems.)

As ZeroTheHero explained, $\hat{r}$ is a radial unit vector. In spherical coordinates there are also tangential unit vectors $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$, but you don’t need these to write a purely radial field, such as for a point charge.

If you are deriving the field from the potential using $\mathbf{E}=\vec\nabla\varphi$, you can write the gradient operator in Cartesian coordinates as

$$\vec\nabla=\hat{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

or in spherical coordinates as

$$\vec\nabla=\hat{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\hat{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\hat{\phi}\frac{1}{r\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}.$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Answer (score 0):

In many E&M textbooks:

1. One tends not to use $i$ because it's also used for current.
2. One tends not to use $j$ because it's also used for current density.
3. One tends not to use $k$ because it's also used for wave vectors.

$\hat r$ is the unit vector in the radial direction in spherical coordinates.

Comment: In Cartesian coordinates, $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$ *are* sometimes used as unit vectors, rather than $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$.

Comment: @G.Smith, I think it's clear that Zero knows thta, but is explaining why it would be confusing to use those names in an electromagnetics problem.

Comment: Using $i$, $j$, and $k$ with hats to make them unit vectors is no more confusing than using $x$, $y$, and $z$ with hats to make them unit vectors. In both cases, if you leave off the hat you get something else.

Comment: @G.Smith IMO the core problem is with math people using $\hat i$, $\hat j$ and $\hat k$, not with physics people using $\hat x$, $\hat y$ and $\hat z$, which is a lot more natural: after all we talk of the $x$-axis and the $x$-component.  Anyways...  In E&M it's better to stay away from $i$, $j$ $k$ because of other usage, like $j$ is also the imaginary unit because $i$ is already the current.  We can agree that notation of unit vector is the least of problems in E&M.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm not sure that I see your reasoning here. After all, $z$ and $x$ are used as symbols for impedance and reactance, respectively, in AC circuits, and $y$ is used to refer to rapidity in relativistic electrodynamics. Ultimately, it's probably an arbitrary convention.

Comment: @probably_someone right... one always runs into exhaustion of the alphabet at some point but there is such a thing as $\vec k$, and $\vec j$.  It is arbitrary to some extent, although the $\hat i, \hat j$ and $\hat k$ tends to be preferred in math texts whereas (in my experience anyways) $\hat x, \hat y$ and $\hat z$ are more common in physics texts.  Just pointing to the reason why E&M tend to use the $\hat x$ etc convention.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero In phasor notation, impedance and reactance are also vectors, and rapidity also has a 3-vector projection, so I still don't see your point. Why does there have to be a reason in the first place?

Comment: @probably_someone I think we're actually getting away from the original intent.  Agreed it's a convention, which doesn't need any more justification than usage.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ok, so why does your answer include an attempt at a justification, and why does it not say that it's just a convention?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I agree with you that $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$ are more common in physics than $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$,  and $\hat{k}$ are, and they make more sense to me. They are consistent with the names of the Cartesian coordinates, just like the spherical unit vectors are consistent with the names of the spherical coordinates. I was just taking issue with your language "One cannot use...".

Comment: @G.Smith yeah I changed it to better reflect usage and what I had in mind.